# TSQL: How to fix output of one of the column from join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a scenario wherein i have an output after two table `JOIN` as follow.

```
Products    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
ABC         81      23      65      94
DEF         70      85      61      63
GHI         95      87      12      19
PQR         53      15      31      61
XYZ         40      67      29      37
```

In this output we have a requirement that the value of the first column is must even when the values of the col1, col2, col3 and col4 are null.

To obtain this output i have used `LEFT JOIN` but their are some scenarios where the WHERE clause does not satisfy and the results are not retrieved and in this situation all the PRODUCT mandatory values are not retrieved.

Example:

```
SELECT 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.t1_Id
WHERE t2.Date between somedate
```

I have also tried capturing individual values in variable using CASE-WHEN statement using below query and then Union the results with hard coding the PRODUCTS value.

```
SELECT @v_ABC_Col1 = CASE WHEN Products = 'ABC' THEN Col1 ELSE 0 END,
      @v_ABC_Col2 = CASE WHEN Products = 'ABC' THEN Col2 ELSE 0 END,
      @v_ABC_Col3 = CASE WHEN Products = 'ABC' THEN Col3 ELSE 0 END,
     @v_ABC_Col4 = CASE WHEN Products = 'ABC' THEN Col4 ELSE 0 END
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.t1_Id
    WHERE t2.Date between somedate
```

But this is not yielding correct results and overwriting the variable value to '0'. Please suggest what is the best way to fix the "Products" column value even if `JOIN` and `WHERE` condition do not matches.

Comment: Can you explain what `in this output we have a requirement that the value of the first column is must even when the values of the col1, col2, col3 and col4 are null` means?

Comment: Are you saying that all records from table t1 should be displayed even if there is no match in t2?

Comment: change the `Where` to `And` so the date limit is applied on the join instead of after.  Anytime you have a outer join and a where clause on the right side of a left join or left side of a right join, you have to put the limit on the join; or use an OR statement to keep the NULL records or the where clause causes the join to act like an INNER Join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you're encountering is because you're negating the OUTER JOIN by having a where clause that limits on the right side table of a left join.

Change it to:

```
SELECT 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.t1_Id
 AND  t2.Date between somedate
```

By moving the limit to the join, it isapplied with the join so the all records from t1 are retained.  By having the limit in the where clause, the NULL records generated by the left join are excluded since the t2.date would be null; and not between somedate (thus making it act like an inner join).

The issue arises due to the order of operations .  The join occurs first which causes the null records in t2 to be created; but then you exclude the NULL records caused by the left join by saying `WHERE t2.date between somedates`.    By moving the limit to the join itself you're saying keep all t1 records and join in only those that have a date between some date and where the ID's match.  which allows those records from t1 to be kept when no match is found in t2.

Less desirable

```
SELECT 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.t1_Id
WHERE (t2.Date between somedate OR t2.date is null)
```

In the above case the t2.date could be NULL because the value itself is null; or could be null because the JOIN results in a null value.